# How to change the background of a movieviewplayercontroller's view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

When I load the movie into the movie player's view it has a black background, I want a white background.

I set the background color of the containing view and the moviecontroller's view and it doesn't change the background color.  Any ideas?

Comment: videoMPPlayer.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [uicolor whitecolor];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

videoMPPlayer.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [uicolor whitecolor];